# How can I turn off “iTunes incoming connection” warning?

Tags: macos, itunes, firewall

I have enabled my firewall on Mac OS X Lion. And now every single time I open iTunes I get this warning:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options

Make sure iTunes is on the list and set to "Allow Incoming Connections" and that you check "Automatically allow signed software to receive incoming connections". If iTunes is not on that list, click the + at the bottom left of the list of programs.

Comment: This doesn't work with me!

Comment: Which part?
Are the settings as I described above, or can you not change any of them?
More information, please.

Comment: iTunes was on the list, I removed it and added it again, but I still get the warning.

Comment: As long as that check-box is checked to ""Automatically allow signed software to receive incoming connections"...I don't see a reason it is still bothering you.
Do you have a security software on your computer?